# Let $X=\mathbb Z^+$. Topologize $X$ with the finite complement topology. Let $A=\{3,5,6,7\}$. Find $\overline A$, int$(A)$, and bdry$(A)$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $X=\mathbb Z^+$. Topologize $X$ with the finite complement topology. Let $A=\{3,5,6,7\}$. Find closure of $A$ $(\overline A)$, interior of $A$ (int$(A)$), and boundary of $A$ (bdry$(A)$).

$A$ is finite and so its compliment is infinite which implies $A$ is not open. $A$ is closed if comp($A$) is open. comp($A$) is open if comp(comp($A$)) is finite. But comp(comp($A$)) $=A$ which is finite. So, comp($A$) is open which implies $A$ is closed. Now, since $A$ is closed, $\overline A=A$.

Since $A$ is finite, the only subset of $A$ which is open is $\varnothing$. Thus, there does not exist an open neighborhood for any $x \in A$. So, int$(A)= \varnothing$.

ext($A$) $=$ int(comp($A$)). Since comp($A$) is open, int(comp($A$)) $=$ comp($A$). So, ext($A$) $=$ comp($A$).

bdry$(A)$ $=$ comp(int($A$) $\cup$ ext($A$)). So, bdry$(A)$ $=$ comp($\varnothing \cup$ comp($A$)) $=$ comp(comp($A$)) $=A$.

**Is this correct?**

Comment: Given the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, the interval $[0,1)$ is not open. Is it closed?

Comment: Noted. Will edit.

Comment: @D.Thomine How does it look now?

Comment: It looks much better. Your argument is mathematically correct. Maybe you could make the computation of the boundary slightly cleaner: the boundary is the closure minus the interior, and you've computed both. But that's a really minor point.